# Highest value in an struct C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, struct

I made an array of the GradesxStudent struct and have been inserting the names of the students and their grades and i got stuck in a wall and can't get trough,

i'm actually trying to get the max value of grades inside the array, but i can't find a way to get trough it.

I made an struct instead of making two arrays.
Note:
There's an error and won't actually even let me compile.

```
    public struct GradesxStudent
    {
      public string student;
      public int grades;
    }
          Console.WriteLine("\nName of the best student");

        for (int i = 0; i < student.Length; i++)
        {

            GradesxStudent m = student.Max();
            GradesxStudent  n = m.grades;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{0,5}", m,n);

        }
```

Error on: `GradesxStudent n = m.grades;`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Students.program.GradesxStudent'

Comment: What is the error? What line is it on?

Comment: in the line "GradesxStudent  n = m.grades;" it says " Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to"Students.program.GradesxStudent'

Comment: and whenever i compile and fill the array and it gets to "GradesxStudent m = student.max();" throws the next exception. {"At least one object must implement IComparable."}

Comment: What object type is `student` in the context of the `for` loop?

Comment: The reason for the error is obvious. But knowing the error and the reason for it does _nothing_ to explain what your _question_ is. What are you actually trying to do? Why are you trying to assign an `int` value to ` GradesxStudent` variable? If the compiler would let you do that, what output would you expect to get? Please explain your question better. (And for what it's worth, you should probably avoid naming your array of objects with the same name as a field within each of those objects.)

Comment: @SumnerEvans student is a string and its the name of the student.

Comment: @PeterDuniho what i'm actually trying to get its the highest grade of  an student in the array. to print it.

Answer (score 1):

You are dotting into the `m` struct to retrieve the `grades` value. The data type of `grades` is `int`. Therefore, `m.grades` is an `int`. You are trying to assign `m.grades` to another `GradexStudent` struct which is invalid.

To make it clearer, would this be valid?

```
GradexStudent n = 3;
```

Of course not.

---

### What you probably want to do instead

```
int n = m.grades;
```

### How to fix `Max()`

I'm assuming `student` is either an `Array` or a `List`. If you want to get the student with the max grade you can use an inline comparison function like so:

```
GradexStudent m = student.Max(s => s.Student.grades);
```